# Visual Studio Dialog Editor Tab (called Toolbox) Gone

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.

I would like to add controls to a dialog-box via the [Dialog Editor Tab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8a4ccy7d.aspx).

It usually appears in my IDE on the left side of the Resource View pane, as a small tag labeled *Toolbox* which I can expand by clicking on.

However, under some circumstances it simply disappears (thank you, Microsoft, for this lovely feature).

I'm not sure about the exact scenario, but it happened after I added a new dialog-box.

Can you please help me recover this?

I tried `TOOLS --> Customize` and `TOOLS --> Options`, but was unable to trace it.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you need exactly since it has been a while since I did MFC projects. However you can always reset your windows layout via selecting from top menu: Windows->Reset Window Layout. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try view -> toolbox, or Ctrl + W,X